# Tail Recursive Fibonacci

Tags: scala, reinventing-the-wheel, fibonacci-sequence

Please critique my implementation of a tail-recursive method for generating the Fibonacci sequence:

```
def fib(n: Int): Option[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(count: Int, prev: Int, acc: Int): Option[Int] = {
        if   (count == n) Some( acc )
        else              go(count+1, acc, acc + prev)
    }
    if      ( n < 0)   None
    else if ( n == 0 ) Some( 0 )
    else if ( n == 1)  Some ( 1 )
    else               go(2, 1, 1)
}
```

Comment: Did you have any particular design goals while [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]? There are alternative solutions, such as a [lazy stream](http://workwithplay.com/blog/2013/09/11/functional-programming-in-scala-evaluation-strategy/).

Answer (score 4):

`go` is under your control, you can guarantee that it will always have a result, so you don't need to use `Option` for it. Also, the special cases for 0 and 1 are not neccessary. Counting backwards instead of forwards is more a matter of taste here, but it *does* reduce the dependency on the outer context.

```
def fib(n: Int): Option[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(count: Int, prev: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
        if (count == 0) acc else go(count-1, acc, acc + prev)
    }
    if ( n < 0) None else Some(go(n, 1, 0))
}
```

However, if you want a really fast implementation (only interesting when you use `BigInt`), you should use these formulas, where you need only ~log(n) iterations instead of n:

$$
\begin{align}
F_{2n-1} &= F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2 \\
F_{2n}   &= (F_{n-1} + F_{n+1}) F_n \\
         &= (2F_{n-1} + F_n) F_n
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Option is not an appropriate type to return here.  There is no doubt about whether a particular input can return a result or not; anything below zero will fail, anything above it will succeed.  For once, failing hard is acceptable in the case of invalid input.

**if...else if...else if...else** chains are fragile and smelly in any language and really never necessary in Scala.  Here, you are testing on precisely the same value each time.  Use pattern matching.

```
  n match {
    case _ if n < 0 => ...
    case _ if n == 0 => ...
    case _ => ...
  }
```